# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined at Client.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I Have a bot that will ask questions in DM and then send the message back to a specified channel.

```
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
    .addField('Name', name)
    .addField('Age', age)
    .addField('Location', location)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor('RED');

  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID);
  await guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'general').send(embed);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous>
```

The channel is there and the Bot has full permissions

Answer (score 0):

I was being a moron and using the wrong GUID All good now :)

Making sure I was using the correct server ID fixed the problem.